# swift display image in another view controller (image view)

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview, photo

I would like to display taken image (VC "First") in another view controller ("Second"). 
When I click a button in "First" I am able to take a photo. Then I see two options: Retake and Use Photo. After I click: Use Photo I am back in vc "First" but I would like to open new vc "Second" and see the image in UIImageView.

I created such code in "First":

```
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) 

    //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Second", sender: self)
}
```

Could You please help me with that problem?

Answer (score 1):

in the First View Controller you could add the class variable:

```
var selectedImage: UIImage?
```

then you switch into the Main.storyboard.

control + click your first View Controller then, drag and drop from the First View Controller to the Second View Controller. Select "show" in the popup to create a segue.

Now select the segue in the interface builder and give it the identifier "Second" in the attributes. (You probably already did that if you had the segue already setup)

then, you could change your present method from this:

```
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to this:

```
self.present(self, animated: true) { 
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Second", sender: self)
        }
```

and add the prepare for segue method in first:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Second" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! Second
            if let image = selectedImage {
                destinationVC.selectedImage = image
            }
        }
    }
```

and in Second you could add the class variable:

```
var selectedImage: UIImage!
```

and set your image view image in the Second View Controller's view did load method

I'm sure there are other ways of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Quickest way, initialise a global Image and pass that image to it.

Write this code in any file (ideally name it appropriately), outside of any class or structure:

```
 var globalImage: UIImage?
```

Then save image from camera there, display it in any VC and when user presses save, add it wherever you want. Just make sure you unwrap the image safely to avoid crashes.

Comment: why was my answer down voted? It solves the requirement